# Dynamically Display Categories and sub-Categories onItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, categories

I'm working on an android application, and now i have to diplay a list of categories, sub-categorie, sub-sub-categorie .... n-sub-categories,  like this:

[image]

At the beggining i want to show the root categories -using a ListView-, and onInClick i want to start i new intent to a new layout, that will display the level 1 sub categories, and then when i click on  a itemp from sub-categories level 1, a new intent starts to open a new layout for sub-categories level-2, and so on unitil i have no sub categories to display,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Same Listview for all categories and sub categories.

When click on the item Use async task to download new sub category List and Modify the data in the List view using data.removeAll() , data.add() and notifydatasetchange()

Comment: if i do that i ll lose all my data except the current sub-categories,

Comment: if you need the previous data then save that to an ArrayList of ArrayList<Modelclass>