# Implement A Mutli Level Listview

Tags: android, listview

What is the best way of implementing multi level listview ?

I have an item that is classified into 1 category and 2 subcategory. So it looks like this

Cat 1 > Sub-cat a > Sub-Sub-cat b > Item > Detail view

Comment: i suggested dear use expandableLIstview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an ExpandableListView ([docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)). However, it does not allow the level of nesting that you need.

To be honest though, I'd recommend against nesting items that deeply into a ListView setup using only ListViews. It makes navigation of the list items difficult/ messy (not to mention the programming side of things, which would be far worse). I would think of doing something along the lines of what follows:

1. Use and ExpandableListView to achieve the Category->Sub-Category layout that you need.
2. From there allow users to "click" on one of the sub categories to replace the ListView with a Fragment (don't forget to put a back button).
3. From the Fragment allow the user to view further details.

This [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/) goes about it a little differently than what I outlined above, but it's good, nonetheless.

This approach will make navigation much easier as well as simplifying your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cat 1 > Sub-cat a > Sub-Sub-cat b > Item > Detail view

Yor are wanting deep nesting instead

Have 4 ListActivity 1st list displays Cat 1 on selecting a cat open another ListActivity with Sub-cat a select on a cat opens ListActivity with Sub-cat b and that opens ListActivity with item and click on an item display the details in a dialog or a activity.

This way it is easier to handle but everytime you view an item you will have to move back 3 time to get the main list.

In deep nesting if there is a large amount of cat and sub cat data u will be loading all at once and filling the list, but in this case you will be fetching only what is required. I dont say this is the best solution. better solution from anyone i will be happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558922/1911784

its working for me .

Expandable List view has only two level if you need more sub levels then you must custom the Expandable List view i think it is a bad thing